# GetResponse API v3 - Get contacts who open the newsletter

Tags: getresponse

I'm having a hard time finding for the API in getting the contacts of the people who open the newsletter after sending it to a list of email. In the official API documentation of GetResponse, I didn't find a solution. Any idea or suggestion can help. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's rather old now, I'll try to answer, maybe it helps someone.

Just as inside GetResponse web interface, you'll need to search contacts according to some criteria. These pages of the API docs describe how this is done:
http://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/resources/search-contacts

Search contacts is the most complex part of the API. To save a search of contacts who opened a particular message you'll need to POST something like below to https://api.getresponse.com/v3/search-contacts/:

```
{
    "name": "test_conditions", //can be any you like
    "subscribersType": [
        "subscribed" //can also be "undelivered", "removed" and "unconfirmed" 
    ],
    "sectionLogicOperator": "or", //or "and"
    "section": [ //section can have up to 8 conditions; one saved search can have up to 4 sections
        {
            "campaignIdsList": [
                "V" //you'll need to get campaigns' IDs with http://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/resources/campaigns#campaigns.get.all
            ],
            "logicOperator": "or",
            "subscriberCycle": [
                "receiving_autoresponder",
                "not_receiving_autoresponder"
            ],
            "subscriptionDate": "all_time", //"today", "yesterday", "this_month", "last_month", "this_week", "last_week" are also possible
            "conditions": [
                {
                  "conditionType": "opened",
                  "operatorType": "message_operator",
                  "operator": "autoresponder", //or "newsletter", or "split"
                  "value": "WTjXF" //message id, should be firstly got with a separate API call
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

More info on how the payload for such requests should be formed is here: http://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/resources/search-contacts-reference

And the last point: if you don't need to save a search but only get the emails who've opened a message, in the object above you should remove the "name" property and post this to http://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/search-contacts/contacts
More: http://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/resources/search-contacts#search-contacts.contacts.form